# Data structure with search, insert and delete in amortised time $O(1)$?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, asymptotics, amortized-analysis

Is there a data structure to maintain an ordered list that supports the following operations in $O(1)$ amortized time?

- **GetElement(k)**: Return the $k$th element of the list.
- **InsertAfter(x,y)**: Insert the new element y into the list immediately after x.
- **Delete(x)**: Remove x from the list.

For the last two operations, you can assume that x is given as a pointer directly into the data structure; InsertElement returns the corresponding pointer for y.  InsertAfter(NULL, y) inserts y at the beginning of the list.

For example, starting with an empty data structure, the following operations update the ordered list as shown below:

- InsertAfter(NULL, a) $\implies$ [a]
- InsertAfter(NULL, b) $\implies$ [b, a]
- InsertAfter(b, c) $\implies$ [b, c, a]
- InsertAfter(a, d) $\implies$ [b, c, a, d]
- Delete(c) $\implies$ [b, a, d]

After these five updates, GetElement(2) should return d, and GetElement(3) should return an error.

Comment: In [Optimal Algorithms for List Indexing and Subset Rank](http://hdl.handle.net/1802/5694) (1989) I found a $\Omega{(\frac{log\ n}{log\ log\ n})}$ solution to this problem.

Comment: By "position" you mean you have reference/pointer to an element in the structure and want to insert next to it? By "$k$-th element" you mean the $k$-largest element, or the one $k$-th inserted? It seems to me that you think of both in terms of arrays, but not all data structures have "positions" in that sense. Please clarify.

Comment: @Raphael: I think he means the element that would be called $A[k]$ if the data structure were an array.  Arrays support the first operation in $O(1)$ time but not the second; linked lists support the second operation in $O(1)$ time but not the first.

Comment: Also, balanced binary trees support both operations in $O(\log n)$ time.

Comment: @JeffE: Sure, but how does this translate to non-linear data structures, i.e. what is the input? Or, in other words, should the required data structures maintain the other of elements, or is it possible to model a set? The question does not specify the desired structure's interface clearly.

Comment: @Raphael: Edited to clarify.

Comment: @JeffE the dynamic array supports the first two in $O(1)$ amortized time (http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1999/09/CS-99-09.pdf)

Comment: @Diego: Read the abstract more carefully: Their data structure only supports inserts and deletions _at the ends_ of the array, not anywhere in the middle.  (Still, a cool result.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the $\Omega(\dfrac{\log n}{\log\log n})$ barrier has been overcome by modifying the analysis from the chronogram technique.

The new [lower] $\Omega(\log n)$ bound has been proved for similar problems in the cell-probe model [1]. From reading that article; it is my understanding that that bound applies to the *list representation* problem also.

---

[1] [Patrascu, Mihai, and Erik D. Demaine. “Logarithmic Lower Bounds in the Cell-Probe Model.” SIAM J. Comput. 35, no. 4 (April 2006): 932–963. doi:10.1137/S0097539705447256.](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mip/papers/loglb/loglb.pdf)

Comment: This lower bound holds for constant-sized words, whereas the earlier $\Omega(\log n/\log\log n)$ lower bound is for logarithmically-sized words.

Comment: Indeed. Also, can you confirm that this bound applies to the *list representation* problem with constant-sized words?

Comment: I can confirm that, because of the Dietz bound (http://hdl.handle.net/1802/5694) that you yourself mentioned. This makes the complexity exactly $\Theta(\log n/\log \log n)$, and therefore *not* $\Omega(\log n)$.

Answer (score 36):

**NO.**

Fredman and Saks proved that *any* data structure that supports these operations requires at least [$\Omega(\log n/\log\log n)$ amortized time per operation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=73040).  (This is reference [1] in the paper by Dietz that you mention in your first comment.)  The lower bound holds in the *very* powerful cell probe model of computation, which only considers the number of distinct memory addresses accessed by the update and query algorithms.

Without some additional assumptions about the update and query operations, Dietz's data structure is the best possible (at least up to constant factors).

Comment: @AT: That bound was never "proved wrong". There are situations where it does not apply, but that is an entirely different statement!

Comment: @AT: The sorting lower bound was proved in a much weaker model of computation, namely binary decision trees.  The bound was "proved wrong" by developing faster algorithms that _cannot_ be described as binary decision trees.  In order to prove Fredman and Saks' lower bound wrong, you'll have to design a faster algorithm **that doesn't access memory**.  Best of luck.

Comment: @JeffE and Raphael; please review my other answer and confirm/deny my result when you get the chance. Thanks.